# jQuery .when().then() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an object which acts as a client side API Client which exposes several functions which all return jQuery ajax() objects. Some of those ajax calls have `.done()` and `.fail()` calls chained directly onto them because they are actions which need to be taken every time the API responses come back before the rest of the js code is allowed to deal with the response. Pretty standard stuff.

I need to kick off a variable number of API requests, wait for all to fail or succeed, and then continue processing. For the examples I will create, I will simplify this down to just two ajax calls.

So I create an array to hold the returned ajax objects, and then use `$.when().apply(null, deferreds).then(function(){//do something after both ajax requests complete})`. When the calls complete successfully, everything works great. When calls fail (such as if the ajax call 404s), things are not so great.

The problem is that `.then()` doesn't seem to detect the fails, [even though I thought `then()` was supposed to be fired regardless of success or failure of the underlying promise(s)](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

I can switch to `.always()`, which seems to work better (in that it detects the failures and still triggers the callback) but it seems to fire before some of the `.fail()` callbacks that are registered directly on the ajax calls, which doesn't make sense to me since I thought the callbacks for an ajax call were called in the order they were registered.

I'm sure I'm just missing something about the behavior of the `ajax()` `when()` `then()` combo.

Fiddle showing successful calls using `.then()`: https://jsfiddle.net/kwrLyw6q/5/

Fiddle using `.then()` with failed ajax calls (not working, would love to know why. Seems like this is the "right" way to do it, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong): https://jsfiddle.net/kwrLyw6q/2/

Fiddle using `.always()` (working, but notice the out-of-order callback order. At least, out of order compared to the order I want them!): https://jsfiddle.net/kwrLyw6q/7/

Comment: You're running `.then()` on the result of `.apply()`, which is different than the result of `$.when()`. Place your `deferreds` comma separated in [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and `.then()` will work as expected: run `error` on first `error` and success on all `success`.

Comment: But this is a simplified case where the number of defferreds is known - in the actual case there are a variable number of defferreds, so I must use apply. I'll edit that into the question. However, why is it that `always()` works when `then()` does not when chained to `apply()`?

Comment: Also, unless I'm misunderstanding, what you're suggesting doesn't seem to work. I created a fiddle demonstrating my implementation of oyur suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/kwrLyw6q/8/ Notice that the "All done" still does not fire.

Comment: You are correct, that's not the reason. You can use `.apply()`. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The weirdest part is that I have this EXACT pattern implemented and working on another project (including when.apply.then), but I cannot for the life of me see the difference between that and this (except that, in that other case, I have wrapped the ajax in a Deferred  for other reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`deferred.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) takes three arguments:

- success function (first argument).
- fail function (second argument).
- progress function (third)

[`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/kwrLyw6q/9/)

Comment: But look at the output - the "All Done" still occurs BEFORE one of the "One task complete" - your solution seems to be the same as the `.always()` fiddle that I posted in the question, just more verbose.

Comment: It occures on the ***first*** failure. It doesn't wait for all to finish. It's a failure function. Only `success` waits for all to finish. Look at [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) documentation: *"In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when() immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred"*.

Comment: Ah, I missed this line in the docs: "In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, _or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected._"
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: Currently trying to find a way to postpone the response and wait for all to finish. It's probably doable by counting all `deferreds` and debouncing the fail execution based on count of responses, but I don't seem to get it right.

Comment: Well there is likely more than one way, but this seems like the perfect place to use jQuery.Deferred(): https://jsfiddle.net/kwrLyw6q/10/

Comment: Yep. Deferring the $ajax failure response makes a lot of sense here. And, btw, my answer was incomplete. It's three arguments. Another one for progress.